# How Google Chrome extension check if a specific app installed on the client machine or not?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to know if it is possible for google chrome extension to check if there is already a native app installed on the client machine or not

Comment: Define "app". Native app? Chrome app? Do you control said app (can modify it to cooperate with the extension)? What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Hi, my extension add custom header to requests made to a specific host and i want only to add these headers in case of native app(windows forms app) is already installed on the client machine.

Comment: Good, you answered almost all of the questions. Last question: are you controlling the app?

Comment: I don't understand you

Answer (score 1):

So we established that you control both the extension and the native app.

Note that the extension cannot access the filesystem to check for existence of files; presumably, you also want to detect the presence of the app even if it's not running, and ideally be able to launch it if it isn't.

The best way to check that the app is installed is to provide a [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) host in the app. The installer would then add a registry key to let Chrome know that the native host is present, and you can connect to it.

Now, there are some considerations:

1. You can't check the presence of the native host without trying to launch it.
2. The process launched that way lives only as long as its communication port is opened in the extension.
3. The communication channel between the extension and the app is the STDIO.

It would not be wise to just declare your main Windows Forms app as the native host. You should write a separate utility app that can communicate according to the Native Messaging protocol (even if to just answer "I'm here"). If needed, it can launch the main app and/or communicate with it as needed using other channels. You could also just launch the main app from your native host and then communicate with it using WebSockets.